# Subjective and objective reality

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

I'd like to talk about two related ideas and ask which philosophers have talked about those.

The first idea is that the "subject", the **I**, has two fundamental aspects: I can *experience* things, and I can *will* some things to happen. I can experience redness, cold, hot, sadness, happiness. I can will myself to stand up from this chair and walk across the room.

The second idea is that this subject invariably meets points of resistance in its experience. There are things the subject cannot will. For example, if I jump up, I will come down and I cannot will myself to fly instead (unless I'm dreaming). There are asperities in my experience that are given and that I cannot will away. These blockers to my will I can call "object". They are not in the subject because they are given to the subject as constraints to its will.

As an observation, when parsing out subjective/objective that way, it seems that the *will* of the subject is critical. It seems to be the trait of the subject that leads to recognizing the existence of objects outside the subject. It seems also that a pure subjectivity in the absence of any object should be conceived as an all powerful will.

Which philosophers have voiced similar or the same ideas (maybe just one, maybe both, maybe some variants)?

Comment: [Schopenhauer, The World as Will](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/schopenhauer/#4), [Nietzsche, The Will to Power](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nietzsche/#WillPowe).

Comment: Regarding Neitzsche, I believe that it was he who said "*A thought comes when it will, not when I will.*" - a sort of Neitzscean epiphenomenalism.

Comment: @Conifold I think the "will to power" is too strong here. I'm interested in "will" only inasmuch as it seems constitutive of the subjective and meets obstacles, which seems a different direction than "will to power"? Does Schopenhauer really take similar positions? Nothing similar in Heidegger?

Comment: I do not get will vibes from Heidegger, it is more encounters and thrownness into the world, and he definitely denies subject as the "first idea". It is the obstacles (un-readiness-to-hand) that break the initial subjectless going on and induce self-awareness and further developments, see [SEP summary](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/heidegger/#ModEnc). Maybe try [Fichte](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/johann-fichte/#SystOverJenaWiss), it is he who starts with "*the I posits itself as an I.*"

Comment: @Conifold I went back to The World as Will and Representation, and it seems Schopenhauer posits a subject and object without much argument to show that an object exists, whereas above the general movement is to show the existence of the object because it impinges on the subject's experience.

Comment: That is his downward motion, from the habitual to the discovery of "it". In the upward motion, there is no subject or objects, there is only the irrational all powerful Will. The Will *is* the world. The so-called subjects are just its "individuations" with mistaken identity and a smokescreen of illusions, like objects and reason, that cover up the Will's unstoppable urges/pushes. One individuation pushes against another, and is urged to push. It is somewhat similar in spirit to Buddhist metaphysics of *maya*, by which he was influenced, only what's behind the *maya* isn't a happy *nirvana*.

Comment: @Conifold Thanks I'll continue reading Schopenhauer. It seems I can see some passages of the text in a different light after thinking about all this. It seems from you say that Schopenhauer makes big ontological claims about "the Will", whereas I was happy to stick to narrower claims.

Comment: There is [Heidegger and the Will: On the Way to *Gelassenheit*](https://www.amazon.com/Heidegger-Will-Gelassenheit-Phenomenology-Existential/dp/0810120356).  In the preview (p.15) Davis quotes from Heidegger's *Nietzsche* Vol.1, The Will to Power as Art: "we are always within the scope of will, even when we are unwilling."

Comment: *To be is to be a value of a bound variable* of the public communication channel, whatever can be communicated successfully *intersubjectively* is an *objective* reality, even one's smile with a flower may get the job done. Even the self-communication of a single islander is objective. Ergo you cannot simply separate objective and subjective realities and claim the object is that which the subject cannot will away or control, otherwise there would be no mind-body interaction topic and the private language argument prevents one even to talk about private subjective realities if they exist...

Comment: @DoubleKnot I don't think objectivity reduces to communication. If that were the case, any dream or fantasy we can communicate would be "objective". At the very least, it's a different definition of "objective". However, "objective" can have a dimension of intersubjectivity, but that's not sufficient.

Comment: Note logically I only claimed a subset of the totality of objective reality which violate your claimed non-will-awayness or non-controllable, since in this case common confusions and misconceptions intersubjectively fixable are objective reality while later could be corrected and *willed way* by all said subjects if they *will* to spend time to think through and correct. I didn't mention those things-in-themselves noumena if they exist in the style of Kant for now...

Comment: @DoubleKnot But precisely, there are things that cannot be will away, intersubjectively or otherwise. Some givens of our experiences are not just intersubjective communication constructs. For example, if you jump up, you'll come down, and _every other_ subject will experience the same, they can't will that one away. Those things that cannot be removed by any subject - but now we assume there are many subjects - are "objective reality".

Comment: I'm not disproving your seemingly intuitive common dictionary definition of *objective* which can be quicky googled here (maybe yet to), I just tried to show a philosophical door to try to enlarge the extension of the concept which is proposed by the postmodern linguistic turn movement to try to improve or correct old metaphysical concepts which are exactly the confused intersubjective fixable cases exemplified above...

Comment: @DoubleKnot "seemingly intuitive common dictionary definition of objective" :-) you have an interesting dictionary ...

Comment: See the first google page search result with (https://www.dictionary.com/browse/objective), line 5, they use the word "not influenced", not much semantic difference from your "not controllable" from a mechanics POV.

Comment: @DoubleKnot In full, it says: "not influenced by personal feelings, interpretations, or prejudice; based on facts; unbiased" - I think that's a slightly different direction for "objective". I don't really see the aspect of an obstacle to a will.

Comment: Different words would always empirically indicate certain different meanings sustained by the repetition of different people's utterances even about the same exact ideal concept, nothing philosophically deep here. OTOH another case where non-hard cold entity couldn't be willed away is from the hint of Godel's 2nd incompleteness or called Löbian obstacle, where a formal ideal system cannot prove certain true statement including its own consistency if it's consistent...